# Prove$\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f(x)\cos 2nx \geq 0$

Tags: calculus

Assume f(x) is convex in $[-\pi,\pi ]$, $f^{'}(x)$ is bounded, Prove:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f(x) \cos 2nx \geq 0$$

Comment: What is the source of the problems you have been posting? Are these homework or are you doing self study and plugging through some problem book?

Comment: @Aryabhata It's truly some questions in a problem book.

Comment: Then please mention the source (including the problem number). btw, did you modify the problem statement?

Comment: Also, this question is very similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120748/sib-2009-problem-2.

Comment: Why no $dx$ in integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've made an answer. Please correct it if anything is wrong.
$$\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f(x) \cos 2nx=-\frac{1}{2n}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^{'}(x)sin2nx$$,then I will prove$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^{'}(x)sin2nx \leq0$.
Divide the interval into $4n$ parts.So the integral becomes

$$\Sigma \int_{-\pi+\frac{k\pi}{2n}}^{-\pi+\frac{k+1\pi}{2n}}f^{'}(x)sin2nx$$,in every interval,$sin2nx$ doesn't change the sign,so use Integral Mean Theorem,and it becomes
$$\Sigma f^{'}(\xi_i)(-1)^{i-1}$$

With f(x) is convex,so $f^{'}(x)$ is increasing.Thus $f^{'}(\xi_i)-f^{'}(\xi_{i+1})\leq0$.

Then we can complete the proof