# to show integration is $\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity

I am given that $f(x)$ is continous on $[0,2\pi]$ and and $f''(x)\ge 0$ on the prescribed interval, I have to show
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos x \; dx \ge 0;$$
well $\cos x\ge 0$ on $[0,\pi/2]$ and $\cos x\le 0$ on $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ and again $\cos x\ge 0$ on $[3\pi/2,2\pi]$, what I did, multiplied with $f''(x) \cos x$ and took the integration by parts, but nothing fruitful I came across; please give hint.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120748/sib-2009-problem-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integration by parts works here, though an appropriate choice of antiderivative is needed. Indeed, observe that
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\cos x \; dx
&= \left[ f(x) \sin x \right]_{0}^{2\pi} - \int_{0}^{2\pi} f'(x)\sin x \; dx \\
&= - \int_{0}^{2\pi} f'(x)\sin x \; dx \\
&= -\left[ f'(x) (1-\cos x) \right]_{0}^{2\pi} + \int_{0}^{2\pi} f''(x)(1-\cos x) \; dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} f''(x)(1-\cos x) \; dx.
\end{align*}$$
Now we find that the integrand $f''(x)(1-\cos x)$ is always non-negative, hence the desired inequality follows.

Comment: using 1-cosx is very smart