# Inequality involving integration

Tags: integration, inequality

Let $f(x)$ be a real valued function whose first, second derivatives are continuous in $[0,2\pi]$. Also, $f''(x)\geq0$.

Show that    $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos{x} dx\geq 0$.

I tried using Integration by parts twice, by which I got

$I= \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos{x} dx\geq 0$

$\implies f'(2\pi)-f'(0)\geq\int_{0}^{2\pi}f''(x)\cos{x}dx$

I know that this LHS should be $\geq0$, but how do I compare it with RHS?

Any hints, solutions or suggestions would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Another solution here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139446/to-show-integration-is-ge-0.